# Headsets compatible with Linux

Tags: microphone

Hello Unix & Linux Community

Right now I'm looking for a new headset for my PC, because my Steel-series Siberia V2 is sometimes working, sometimes not.
I asked in different stores f.e. Gamestop which headsets the best for pc's are. Everyone of them just said Logitech G, but Logitech sais, that their headset are just working with Windows.

Now I wanted to ask you, if somebody knows a good quality headset that's working with Linux as well.

I hope somebody can give me a recommendation.

Greets

Not to forget:
OS: Linux Mint 18.2 (want to switch to Arch Linux)
CPU: Intel Core i7-4770

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily opinion based and is asking for a hardware recommendation.

Comment: The Logitech headsets work just fine on Linux, you just won't be able to use some of the features.  I've got a G35 and it works perfectly fine, it just doesn't let me do anything on Linux that's beyond the default settings (because it's configured by the Logitech Gaming Software and has no persistent configuration).

Comment: a hardware recomendation but it is actually about Linux, do I misunderstood the community policies? +1 for the user it is not fair to receive bad reputation, if his/her question matters! Where is opinion based - what is the user opinion?

Comment: Great question. In general, look at Alsa project for supported devices, as it provides driver support. If Alsa knows it, it will be supported. But how well it is supported is a lottery, because of a war of attrition between Alsa and Pulseaudio. The later does not respect the settings made in Alsa and overwrites/destroys them at every opportunity. Boo-hoo, PulseAudio - you are hated everywhere where sound matters.

Comment: To all, who voted to close this question.  
I'm sorry that I posted this question, but the Unix & Linux just appeared the best Forum to all, because it's a question about hardware working with Linux. I don't know any other forums, who answer question about Linux in general. If I asked on the Linux Mint Forum, I just get hate and my question is getting deleted, because (as you all have mentioned) it's Off-Topic. I really appreciate Luciano Andress Martini for his explanation and his opinion. Thumbs up.
I just wanted to ask other users, who are using a good quality headset on Linux.

Greets

Answer (score 2):

PC headsets either use analog audio or USB audio or Bluetooth audio. They should work with Linux.

Comment: Or Bluetooth. But they should also work...